# Angular : getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins

Tags: angular

On google it is provided that we can run the chrome using `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://example.com` and it will work.

but i want to know if there is any solution or configuration available in our Angular app.so that it will work.

Comment: i m using angular 6

Comment: How `getUserMedia()` is called? With a http call? Have you access to your endpoint?

Comment: yes, its a http call